# H2 DataBase error Caused by: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked:

Tags: database, h2

As am using H2 database am getting the above error and am un aware how to reslove it

ERROR:

Caused by: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked:

Please guide me

trying to connect H2 data base to web page

Answer (score 0):

maybe your config is follow：

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: sa
    password: 123456
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
      settings:
        trace: false
        web-allow-others: true # 允许远程访问
        web-admin-password: 123456
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
    open-in-view: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

notice，"jdbc:h2:~/test" is file mode，and File mode allows only one connection。

You do not need to run the SpringBoot project when you run the unit tests，and code is follow

[项目结构图](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoeXL.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-h2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>springboot-h2</name>
    <description>springboot-h2</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

domian/Book.java

```java
package com.github.domain;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * @author 许大仙
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 2023-02-26 07:42
 */
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String type;

    private String name;

    private String description;

}
```

dao/BookRepository.java

```java
package com.github.dao;

import com.github.domain.Book;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * @author 许大仙
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 2023-03-04 10:01
 */
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

}
```

SpringbootH2Application.java

```java
package com.github;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootH2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootH2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: sa
    password: 123456
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
      settings:
        trace: false
        web-allow-others: true # 允许远程访问
        web-admin-password: 123456
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
    open-in-view: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

SpringbootH2ApplicationTests

```java
package com.github;

import com.github.dao.BookRepository;
import com.github.domain.Book;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class SpringbootH2ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
        Book book = new Book().setName("Java从入门到精通").setType("计算机图书").setDescription("这是一本好的书籍，你不觉得！");
        Book bookDb = this.bookRepository.save(book);
        System.out.println("bookDb = " + bookDb);
    }

}
```